# Reset app on logout. Pop pages from nav stack and delete services data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When a user logs out of my app and another user logs in I want it to act like it hasn’t been used before.
Currently all the pages that have been opened by the first user are still in memory and the same with the injected services. This mean user 2 sees user 1 data.
This is a security concern.

I read that I could use this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(’/login’); to deal with the pages by popping them from the nav stack. Not sure if this works yet as I need to sort the services.

How can I remove all the instantiated/injected services?
I am storing a variable in the services (tenantId) and it is causing havoc as it is not reset at logout.

This is a very uncommon case for the app to have two users on the same device. But I need to deal with it and it is messing up my testing.

Basically I just want to reset the whole app to its initial state on log out.

Apologies if any terminology is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Just reload / refresh the window (`window.location.reload(true);`) on logout. The browser will dump all of the in memory Javascript and reload it and Angular will re run its init process, re do its dependency injection etc. The only remaining issue would be values stored in the cache, but this is easy to cleanse with `localStorage.clear();`

When it comes to clearing the browser navigation you will find more trouble than it is worth. Also its probably not the best user experience as User A may want to see their prior navigation the next time they log in after User B has been in the system.